# IIS Express and ASP.NET 2.0

Tags: asp.net, iis-express

For IIS 7.5 Express, I understand that I can set the CLR version to 2.0 for a site from the command line using the /clr:v2.0 command line argument. For the life of me, I cannot find the documentation that explains how to specify it when using the /site argument. I would have thought it goes in the applicationhost.config file but damned if I can find it. Since the CLR version is website specific I would have thought it went into the  section but...shrug.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You CANNOT use `/clr` switch with `/site` switch
2. You can set clr version to an application, but not a site (A site can have multiple applications)
3. To set clr version to an application, change the application's applicationPool's **managedRuntimeVersion** 
   (Edit the `applicationhost.config` located in `%userprofile%\my documents\iis express\config\` and set the applicationPool's **managedRuntimeVersion** to desired value).

If you have installed WebMatrix, you can do it through UI.
1. Open WebMatrix
2. open site
3. Click Settings tab
4. select the .net framework version

Answer (score 0):

You can use the /clr switch e.g: /clr v2.0

Check this link:

> http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/870/running-iis-express-from-the-command-line/

Comment: I think you misunderstood what I wrote. As I stated, I already know about the command line switch...but my question is how to specify the value using the config file.