# ASP.NET AJAX not working on localhost for .NET 3.5

Tags: asp.net, ajax

The live application has been deployed for a while and works fine. The application pool is v2.0 Classic. It is hosted on Windows Server 2008 R2.

My local environment is Windows 8.1. I'm debugging in IIS Express. I get the following errors in the browser developer tools:

- Uncaught Error: ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework failed to load.
- Uncaught ReferenceError: Sys is not defined

All of the ScriptResource.axd GET requests result in a 404 error. Any ideas on fixing the .NET Ajax?

Btw, I've already done all the suggestions that I've previously seen on how to resolve this, particularly with the handlers. I have the following web.config.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
        <section name="scriptResourceHandler" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
        <sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
          <section name="jsonSerialization" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingJsonSerializationSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="Everywhere"/>
          <section name="profileService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingProfileServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
          <section name="authenticationService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingAuthenticationServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
          <section name="roleService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingRoleServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
        </sectionGroup>
      </sectionGroup>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <!-- snipped -->
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
    <!-- snipped -->
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
        <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Drawing.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
        <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <clear/>
        <add namespace="System"/>
        <add namespace="System.Collections"/>
        <add namespace="System.Collections.Specialized"/>
        <add namespace="System.Configuration"/>
        <add namespace="System.Text"/>
        <add namespace="System.Text.RegularExpressions"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Caching"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.SessionState"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Security"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Profile"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.UI"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.UI.HtmlControls"/>
      </namespaces>
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add tagPrefix="telerik" namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" assembly="Telerik.Web.UI"/>
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <httpHandlers>
      <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
      <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" verb="*" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource, Telerik.Web.UI" validate="false"/>
    </httpHandlers>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </httpModules>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="login.aspx" timeout="120" slidingExpiration="true"/>
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="(snipped)"/>
      <deny roles="(snipped)"/>
      <deny users="?,*"/>
    </authorization>
    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="SimpleRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="SimpleRoleProvider" type="MyProject.SimpleRoleProvider" applicationName="MyProject"/>
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="error">
      <!--<error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />-->
      <error statusCode="500" redirect="error/500.html"/>
    </customErrors>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="240"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated" />
      <add name="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd_*" path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" verb="*" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource, Telerik.Web.UI" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0" />
      <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
       <rule name="API Rule" stopProcessing="true">
         <match url="api/(.*)" />
         <conditions>
           <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
           <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
           <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="/api/PublicService\.svc.*" negate="true" />
         </conditions>
         <action type="Rewrite" url="api/PublicService.svc/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*"/>
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:0}"/>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
    <modules>
      <remove name="ScriptModule"/>
      <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <location path="ScriptResource.axd">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <!-- other locations snipped -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <extensions>
      <behaviorExtensions>
        <add name="MyWebHttpBehaviorExtension" type="MyProject.CustomBehaviorExtensionElement, MyProject, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
        <add name="MyFaultHiderBehaviorExtension" type="MyProject.FaultHiderBehaviorExtensionElement, MyProject, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
      </behaviorExtensions>
    </extensions>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyProject.AspNetAjaxBehavior">
          <enableWebScript/>
          <MyWebHttpBehaviorExtension/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyProject.AspNetAjaxBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
    <services>
      <service name="MyProject.Api.PublicService">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="MyProject.AspNetAjaxBehavior" bindingConfiguration="WebServicesBinding" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="MyProject.Api.PublicService"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WebServicesBinding">
          <security mode="None"/>
        </binding>
        <binding name="WebServicesBindingHttps">
          <security mode="Transport"/>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="GatewaySoap" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.codedom>
      <compilers>
        <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" warningLevel="4">
          <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
          <providerOption name="OptionInfer" value="true"/>
          <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
      </compiler>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding appliesTo="v2.0.50727" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions.Design" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

I have double-checked the AXD handler in the applicationhost.config for IIS Express. It appears that I have .NET 2.0 AXD handlers. (But I have little expertise in interpreting these.)

```
    <handlers accessPolicy="Read, Script">
        <!-- non-AXD handlers snipped -->
        <add name="AXD-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*.axd" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
        <add name="AXD-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*.axd" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
        <add name="TraceHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="trace.axd" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="System.Web.Handlers.TraceHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
        <add name="WebAdminHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="WebAdmin.axd" verb="GET,DEBUG" type="System.Web.Handlers.WebAdminHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
        <add name="AssemblyResourceLoader-Integrated-4.0" path="WebResource.axd" verb="GET,DEBUG" type="System.Web.Handlers.AssemblyResourceLoader" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
        <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices-Integrated-4.0" path="*_AppService.axd" verb="*" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
        <add name="ScriptResourceIntegrated-4.0" path="*ScriptResource.axd" verb="GET,HEAD" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
        <add name="TraceHandler-Integrated" path="trace.axd" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="System.Web.Handlers.TraceHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0" />
        <add name="WebAdminHandler-Integrated" path="WebAdmin.axd" verb="GET,DEBUG" type="System.Web.Handlers.WebAdminHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0" />
        <add name="AssemblyResourceLoader-Integrated" path="WebResource.axd" verb="GET,DEBUG" type="System.Web.Handlers.AssemblyResourceLoader" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0" />
        <add name="AXD-ISAPI-2.0" path="*.axd" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv2.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
        <add name="AXD-ISAPI-2.0-64" path="*.axd" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv2.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
    </handlers>
```

Comment: check if you have *.axd in your handler mappings in IIS. On my machine it is mapped to %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll

Comment: See additional info above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. The problem was not with my web.config. In fact, I could not find any problem with any of my files or code. Ultimately, I had to recreate the project and copy my files in. Specifically, in order:

1. Create new empty ASP.NET project. (Visual Studio did this in 4.5 by default.)
2. Change the target framework to version 3.5.
3. Copy the code files from the current project.
4. In the project properties of the new project, make sure that the assembly name and root namespace of the new project match that of the existing project.
5. Add the necessary references in the new project.
6. Run the new project in debug mode, to test it, confirming that all works as it should.
7. Copy everything back, overwriting the old project, with the following caveats:

   1. There is no need to overwrite the old solution (in my situation, anyway).
   2. Be sure to overwrite the old VS proj file, and the bin folder.
   3. I am using Git for source control, so it will automatically pick up any files that are new/different, and ignore others.
8. In my case, there are two possibilities (that I can think of) for the source of the problem. I don't know which is the real cause:

   1. I was missing `/My Project/MyExtensions/MyWebExtension.vb`.
   2. Something in the vsproj file itself.

Answer (score 0):

As the site is configured to run in .NET 2.0 (or possibly 3.5) you need to install the AJAX control toolkit DLLs in your bin, as they are likely installed to the GAC on the production server, which is why it works there. In order for it to be able to load the 2.0 DLLs you'll need to either install the DLLs to the GAC on your machine or include them in the bin directory. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40116/how-do-i-install-and-use-the-asp-net-ajax-control-toolkit-in-my-net-3-5-web-app) should help with that.

Comment: It is already in the project's bin folder, and the reference points to it. Nonetheless, it was toolkit version 1.0.20229, which I guess is for ASP.NET AJAX 1.0 and .NET Framework 2.0. I downloaded the new toolkit (version 3.5.20229, for .NET Framework 3.5), replaced the DLL file, and recreated the reference. (Leaving the original reference kept the project from even building after pasting in the new file.) There is no change in behavior with the new DLL/reference. I get the same errors.

Comment: [DId you configure IIS Express to use classic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5914744/force-iis-express-to-classic-pipeline-mode)? You may also [need to configure the site's app pool to 2.0 in IIS Express](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890394/iis-express-and-asp-net-2-0).

Comment: I did. It is configured for 2.0. The app pool name is Clr2ClassicAppPool with `managedRuntimeVersion="v2.0" managedPipelineMode="Classic"`.