# Uncuaght SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<': WebResource.axd?, ScriptResource.axd, ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework failed to load

Tags: internet-explorer, asp.net-ajax, microsoft-edge, webresource.axd, scriptresource.axd

I am trying to make the current asp.net web form (with .net framework 3.5, vb.net) application run on the Microsoft Edge browser. There is no issue in IE, it has been working fine on IE and still works fine. But when I open in Edge browser it throws the error shown in the screenshot:

Also, it doesn't throw this error in Edge browser when I run from Visual Studio in localhost. It runs perfectly fine.

[Screenshot of Error messages in edge browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTimJ.png)

[I've tried solution #4 in this link's first answer and because other solutions #1 & #2 are already there in the code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11288796/asp-net-ajax-client-side-framework-failed-to-load-when-put-the-scriptmanager-on)

Comment: You say when you test in localhost, Edge doesn't make this error. How did you run the test and produce the error in Edge? In the error message showing in console, "<" may cause the page label to correspond incorrectly. Have you tried to fix this issue? Besides, I found a [similar case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30945107/asp-net-ajax-not-working-on-localhost-for-net-3-5/30947724), you can also refer to it. We can have a test and try to help if you can provide [a minimal code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that can **reproduce the issue**.

Comment: Yu Zhou: Thank you for your response.  This is a legacy system that has been perfectly working in IE, now they want me to test on Edge browser as IE won't be available soon.  I just opened the URL in Edge instead of in IE without changing anything in the code and it threw an error. But for some reason, it doesn't throw the error if I run from the visual studio and I can login successfully. I don't think "<" is the issue, I believe that issue is because of something not working/supporting by Edge when it is hosted in IIS. Producing minimal code snippets is kinda hard, I will see what I can do.

Comment: There will be no such error in IIS-related issues. You can also refer to [this case](https://forums.asp.net/t/2169673.aspx?Uncaught+SyntaxError+Unexpected+token+) appropriately. I see [that case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11288796/asp-net-ajax-client-side-framework-failed-to-load-when-put-the-scriptmanager-on) you referred to is for .net 4, and your environment is .net 3.5. I assume that the module version configured by **web.config** does not match. So could you provide the relevant configuration in **web.config**? This can help narrow the scope of the problem.

Comment: Besides, have you tried Edge IE mode to see if it can fix the issue: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode